# How to retrieve and modify a list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-visualization

I have a list and I want to retrieve and modify it.

Like If I want to change fontsize from 14px to 10px.

Also I am not able to alert it in a different function even thought its in a global variable.

alert(options) shows **undefined**.

```
 var options = {                
                colors: ['#795548', '#EF851C', '#6633CC'],               
                fontsize: "14px",              
               }
```

Actually I am working on google charts and want to get this static list(declared globally) in below function.

**Calling function :-**

```
  function LoadCurrentChartData(currentChart) {       
  alert(options);
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('Graph1'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: You need to give us the whole picture so we can identify the problem.

Comment: how do you build this object?

Comment: how do you change the props in the object?
 http://jsbin.com/gixahesiqe/edit?js,console

Comment: this is a static object with 2 properties colors and fontsize and declared globally, I want to retrieve this object in another jQuery function as its a global variable thus its scope is throughout the page..

Comment: how you are calling share other function also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your variable before using this. Check below

```js
function func1(){
  console.log(options.fontsize);
}
//func1();//calling from here will give error
var options = {                
   colors: ['#795548', '#EF851C', '#6633CC'],
   fontsize: "14px",
}
func1();
//Edit fontsize value 
options.fontsize = "10px";
console.log("After chage");
func1();
```

Comment: Can I modify this value ?